# Browser displays HTML code as it is, written by a C program to a socket

Tags: html, c, sockets, http, webserver

I have the following C program, that writes text in HTML syntax to port 5010.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    char* sendBuff="<html><head><title>page 1</title></head></html>";
    time_t ticks; 
    uint32_t ip = 0;
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    //memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 
    inet_aton("127.0.0.1", (struct in_addr*)&ip);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(ip);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5010); 

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    listen(listenfd, 10); 

    while(1)
    {
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 
    fprintf(stderr, "New connection \n");
        ticks = time(NULL);
        //snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
        write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff)); 

        close(connfd);
        sleep(1);
     }
}
```

And then I issue the following request in my browser's address bar:

```
127.0.0.1:5010
```

I was expecting my browser to show the title of page as "page1", but instead it rendered the HTML code as it is.
[image: Browser Output]

Comment: Are you sending http headers? Specially `Content-Type: text/html`?

Comment: @iharob: No I am just writing the a string made of some html tags.

Comment: The HTTP protocol is not THAT simple. You should investigate it a little.

Comment: I got it... At this point of time, the browser cant make any sense of my data...thus it dumps it, as it is. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you type "127.0.0.1:5010" into your browser bar, it assumes the server on the other side is speaking the HTTP protocol. Your browser will automatically change your URL to `http://127.0.0.1:5010/`. This means the server on the other side must respond with a valid HTTP response.

The HTTP protocol requires you to pass more than just the data that you want to display. For example, here's a server response for a very simple web page:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Content-Length: 89

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>page 1</title></head><body>Hello World!</body></html>
```

Furthermore, your browser cannot know to display the content as HTML unless you actually send it a `Content-Type` header with an appropriate value.

For more details on the HTTP protocol, you may want to read the [corresponding Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) or the following 6 RFCs which actually define the current HTTP 1.1 specification:

- [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230)
- [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231)
- [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232)
- [RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233)
- [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234)
- [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235)

Comment: Correct, good explanation, but link to outdated HTTP specification.